# What is the format for adding a compliance standard to an existing policy with the Prisma Cloud API?

Tags: python, json

I'm having trouble adding a Compliance Standard to an existing Policy via the Pal Alto Prisma Cloud API.

Everytime I send the request, I'm returned with a 500 Server Error (and, unfortunately, the API documentation is super unhelpful with this). I'm not sure if I'm sending the right information to add a compliance standard as the API documentation doesn't show what info needs to be sent. If I leave out required fields (name, policyType, and severity), I'm returned a 400 error (bad request, which makes sense). But I can't figure out why I keep getting the 500 Server Error.

In essence, my code looks like:

```py
import requests

url = https://api2.redlock.io/policy/{policy_id}

header = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-redlock-auth': 'token'}

payload = {
    'name': 'policy_name',
    'policyType': 'policy_type',
    'severity': 'policy_severity',
    'complianceMetadata': [
        {
            'standardName': 'standard_name',
            'requirementId': 'requirement_ID',
            'sectionId': 'section_id'
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.request('PUT', url, json=payload, header=header)
```

The response should be a 200 with the policy's metadata returned in JSON format with the new compliance standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those using the RedLock API, I managed to figure it out.

Though non-descriptive, 500 errors generally mean the JSON being sent to the server is incorrect. In this case, the payload was incorrect.

The correct JSON for updating a policy's compliance standard is:

```py
req_header = {'Content-Type':'application/json','x-redlock-auth':jwt_token}

# This is a small function to get a policy by ID
policy = get_redlock_policy_by_ID(req_header, 'policy_ID')

new_standard =  { 
         "standardName":"std-name",
         "requirementId":"1.1",
         "sectionId":"1.1.1",
         "customAssigned":true,
         "complianceId":"comp-id",
         "requirementName":"req-name"
      }

policy['complianceMetadata'].append(new_standard)

requests.put('{}/policy/{}'.format(REDLOCK_API_URL, policy['policyId']), json=policy, headers=req_header)
```